# Date difference between UIDatepicker and NSDate

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.2, nsdate

I have a datepicker and I save the value to .plist file with key UserDate in string format.

The value returns from datepicker is in `2013-02-13 11:17:34 +0000` format.

In order to save it into to .plist file I need to convert datepicker to string `2013-02-14T19:17:34Z`

In other View, I want to retrieve back the UserDate from plist and compare with the user current date. I want days and hours different.

I convert and pass `2012-02-12 19:17:34 +0800` as `destinationDate` to compare with [NSDate new].
I managed to calculate the difference between two date. But the result is not correct.

### How to get the correct difference result for two dates between iPhone's date and Datepicker's date? Do I need to use a specific timezone?

**Extra info**: I live in GMT+8. I set the simulator datepicker to Feb 13 2012, yet the result still say the countdown has 18hours and 4 minutes.

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
int units = NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;

NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:units fromDate:[NSDate date] toDate:destinationDate options:0];
[datelabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%c %d%c %d%c %d%c %d%c", [components month], 'm', [components day], 
                    'd', [components hour], 'h', [components minute], 'm', [components second], 's']];
```

NSLog

[image]

**Edit**

Plist file.

[image]

save method

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
// get documents path
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
// get the path to our Data/plist file
NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.plist"];

// set the variables to the values in the text fields
self.userTitle = myTitle.text;
self.userMessage = myMessage.text;  

NSLog(@"METHOD SAVE");

NSLog(@"Datepicker value =  %@", myDate.date );

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"];
NSString *mdate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:myDate.date];
//  [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"];

NSLog(@"Converted from date picker, save into plist =  %@", mdate );

self.saveDate = mdate;
//self.userDate = myDate.date;

// create dictionary with values in UITextFields
NSDictionary *plistDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: userTitle, userMessage, saveDate, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Title", @"Message", @"UserDate", nil]]; NSString *error = nil;
// create NSData from dictionary
NSData *plistData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:plistDict format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 errorDescription:&error];

// check is plistData exists
if(plistData)
{
    // write plistData to our Data.plist file
    [plistData writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
    
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success" message:@"Your settings have been saved." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Ok",nil];
    [alert show];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Error in saveData: %@", error);
    //[error release];
}
```

viewWillAppear

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];

[super viewWillAppear:animated];

// Data.plist code
// get paths from root direcory
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
// get documents path
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
// get the path to our Data/plist file
NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.plist"];

// check to see if Data.plist exists in documents
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistPath])
{
    // if not in documents, get property list from main bundle
    plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Data" ofType:@"plist"];
}

// read property list into memory as an NSData object
NSData *plistXML = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:plistPath];
NSString *errorDesc = nil;
NSPropertyListFormat format;
// convert static property liost into dictionary object
NSDictionary *temp = (NSDictionary *)[NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:plistXML mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves format:&format errorDescription:&errorDesc];
if (!temp)
{
    NSLog(@"Error reading plist: %@, format: %d", errorDesc, format);
}

NSLog(@"Plist Title: %@", [temp objectForKey:@"Title"]);
NSLog(@"Plist Message: %@", [temp objectForKey:@"Message"]);
NSLog(@"Plist date: %@", [temp objectForKey:@"UserDate"]);

userTitle.text = [NSString localizedStringWithFormat:@"%@", [temp objectForKey:@"Title"]];
userMessage.text = [NSString localizedStringWithFormat:@"%@", [temp objectForKey:@"Message"]];

//http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070354/how-do-i-get-the-current-date-in-cocoa

NSDate* now = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:3600];
userCoundown.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",now];  

NSString *uDate = [[NSString alloc] init];
uDate = [temp objectForKey:@"UserDate"];
NSLog(@"Plist date in string - %@", uDate);

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"];
NSDate *ddate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:uDate];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss Z"];

NSLog(@"Format date from Plist -  %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:ddate]);

//NSLog(@"GMT format from Plist - %@", timeStamp);

//http://www.epochconverter.com/#
destinationDate = ddate;
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateLabel) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

updatelabel

```
-(void)updateLabel {

NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
int units = NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;

NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:units fromDate:[NSDate date] toDate:destinationDate options:0];
[datelabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%c %d%c %d%c %d%c %d%c", [components month], 'm', [components day], 
                    'd', [components hour], 'h', [components minute], 'm', [components second], 's']];
}
```

Comment: You can save an `NSDate` directly into a plist, it will be automatically converted to an ISO 8601 string format. On reading the plist the `NSData` will be converted back to an `NSDate`.

Comment: You should show us more of your code; ideally an entire sequence of statements that reproduces the problem, not just a small portion of it, and especially the code you're using to 1) convert an NSDate into a string and save it to the plist 2) retrieve the date from the plist and make it into a date.

Comment: top comment is right..but incomplete..:P .. you can save array,dictionary,data,string,integers etc in a plist file directly.. just make an array with an NSDate object and make a plist of it...then later get the plist..get the array..and you will get the appropriate date at its objectAtIndex :0 ..then compare..

Answer (score 0):

NSDate keeps time in GMT. If you have time zones you will have to specify them.

The question is not clear so this is not a complete answer but should provide some help with `NSDate` in a plist.

Here is an example of creating, writing and reading a plist with a `NSDate`:

```
NSDictionary *plistDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                           userTitle,   @"Title",
                           userMessage, @"Message",
                           saveDate,    @"UserDate",
                           nil];

[plistDict writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

NSDictionary *plistDictRead = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSDate *dateRead = [plistDictRead objectForKey:@"UserDate"];
```

There is no need to convert the `NSDate` to a string and no need to use `NSPropertyListSerialization`.

Comment: I have edited the question. What I need is the correct result calculation between my datepicker and iphone date. Today is 13 Feb 2012, I set the simulator datepicker to Feb 13 2012, yet the result still say the countdown has 18hours and 4 minutes. sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to create the NSDate and then output it with a **valid timezone and calendar**!

Check a similar question I answered in another post:
[UIDatePicker return wrong NSDate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356565/uidatepicker-return-wrong-nsdate/11888814#11888814)