# DatePicker problems in swift

Tags: datepicker, swift, hour

(Sorry for my english)

I made a button to get the value of the DatePicker but the hours in the output is 4 hour late than in the DatePicker

My code:

```
@IBOutlet var date: UIDatePicker!

@IBAction func sauvegarderClicked(sender: AnyObject) {

    println(date.date)
}
```

Is this the correct way to get the value from the DatePicker ?

And at the end of the output there is a "+0000" how can i remove this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIDatePicker return wrong NSDate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356565/uidatepicker-return-wrong-nsdate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date picker gives you the date in GMT.

Take a look at [NSDateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1) which will do what you want.

Comment: I did:

var date :NSDate = (NSDate.date());

var dateFormater : NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter();

dateFormater.dateFormat = "dd:mm:yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz";

But now when i print the date i get: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: did you do this?: let s = dateFormater.stringFromDate(date)