# find EST date now in objective-c iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nstimezone

Coming to point i need to find the `EST` time now, but i have written below function this will return incorrect time to me, I didn't point out where i made  a mistake or I've written wrong code ,
any one can drive me in a way would be highly appreciate-able.

**@ROB the response will be like that : "close_ts" = "2014-11-21T01:25:00"**

```
 + (NSDate *)currentESTDate
{
    NSString *formatterDate = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";

    NSDate* date = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"EST"]];
    [formatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc]initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]];
    [formatter setDateFormat:formatterDate];
    NSString* currentDateStamp = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
    NSDate * returnDate = [formatter dateFromString:currentDateStamp];

    if( returnDate )
    {
        return returnDate;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: What's the point of converting the current date to a string and then converting that string back to a date and returning that date? Why not just use `[NSDate date]` as-is?

Comment: @rmaddy i need est format current date, but  NSString* currentDateStamp = [formatter stringFromDate:date]; this will return exact time  in string format, i need that in date formate so i convert that to again [formatter dateFromString:currentDateStamp]  this will give a false time .

Comment: See Rob's answer. It seems you have some confusion of how dates work.

Comment: If you search S.O. for questions about getting `NSDate` in particular timezone, perhaps that will provide useful background. E.g. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485493/get-nsdate-from-nsdate-adjusted-with-timezone

Comment: @rmaddy pls look at Once i have updated few lines of code and i need to pass the values

Comment: please mention the reason for downwote ?

Comment: I didn't down-vote, but I'd guess it was down-voted because this has been asked many times. It's a common stumbling block when people first start using `NSDate`. No offense intended, but it's not clear how much research you did looking for similar questions before asking it again, yourself. I personally cut you a little slack because the connection between the original question "how do I convert timezone of `NSDate` object" and the root problem (failure to convert `2014-11-21T01:25:00` properly) is not entirely obvious. But both topics have been covered exhaustively here before. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say the time is reported as `2014-11-21T01:25:00`. That's a typical [RFC 3339](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt)/[ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date. See Apple's [Technical Q&A QA1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1480/_index.html) for information on how to parse, which is usually:

```
NSLocale *enUSPOSIXLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.locale = enUSPOSIXLocale;
formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss";
formatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:timeStamp];
```

Note, in this format, the timestamp is almost always in `GMT`, not `EST`. To remove this ambiguity, most dates strings we get from servers are generally bear a `Z` at the end, e.g. `2014-11-21T01:25:00Z` to unambiguously declare that the date in "Zulu", i.e. `GMT`/`UTC`. Even in the absence of timezone information, we'd generally expect this to still be `GMT`. If you know for a fact that it's really `EST` (which I highly doubt; that would be very unusual), then change the `timeZone` line above (using your `timeZoneWithAbbreviation`).

That's how you convert the date string you received from the server into a `NSDate`. You can then compare that to `[NSDate date]` as contemplated in your `isEndDate:isSmallerThanCurrent:` routine. But do not try to convert a `NSDate` into a different timezone.

---

You say `currentESTDate` returns the incorrect time. The `NSDateFormatter` will calculate the current date and time in EST in the `currentDateStamp` variable. But you then convert it back, just retrieving the original `NSDate` value. Thus this routine is unnecessary.

To be clear, `NSDate` objects do not have timezones. They represent the same moment of time across the entire world. The time zones only come into play when you convert the date into a string (via `NSDateFormatter`).

Thus, the problem is not "how do I convert `[NSDate date]` into a particular timezone." The question is how one converts the `2014-11-21T01:25:00` string from the server into a valid `NSDate` object (which can then be compared to other `NSDate` objects). And hopefully the above code answers that question.

Comment: actually my primary concern is to compare 2 dates one is service returns the EST date and i need to convert my date to current EST date, then how it works last one fullday i analysed and searched all the possible things but i didn't got idea.

Comment: my question is dublicate one ?…. pls suggest me

Comment: @Spynet Yeah, it's a duplicate, but I cut you a little slack as this is one of those questions that it's hard to find good answers (unless you already know the answer). lol. Regarding parsing `2014-11-21T01:25:00` format, search for "[ios] nsdate t" (though, many of the answers out there neglect the subtlety of setting the `locale`, too). Regarding original `NSDate`/timezone question, search for "[ios] nsdate current time zone", and you'll find some promising links (this misconception about `NSDate` and timezones is pretty common, as you'll see, so don't feel bad).