# What is the timezone for [NSDate date]?

Tags: ios, objective-c, datetime, timezone, nsdate

I have a question about how timezone in [NSDate date] works. In my app, I am making a PUT web service call in which I have to send in the date in UTC, converted to milliseconds.

```
-(NSNumber *) dateToMillis: (NSDate *) date
{
   long long val = (long long)[date timeIntervalSince1970] *1000.0;
   return @(val);
} 

NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSLog(@"Date - %@", [self dateToMillis:date]);

NSTimeInterval timeZoneSeconds = [[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"CST"] secondsFromGMT];
NSDate *dateInUTC = [date dateByAddingTimeInterval:timeZoneSeconds];   
NSLog(@"Date UTC - %@", [self dateToMillis:dateInUTC]);
```

I assumed [NSDate date] would be in local timezone (CST) and tried to convert it to UTC, but both NSlogs print exactly the same value.

Does [NSDate date] not return the date time in local timezone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An NSDate represents a point in the continuum of time, which is independent of time zones or locale. Looking at that date in a time zone is a "view" of that time (i.e. "what do WE call that time in the temporal continuum?").

If your goal is to show a time in your current time zone, look at NSDateFormatter: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/ - you can set the time-zone (and the locale, if you want) to display in the formatter, and it will show you what that date is referred to as in that time zone / locale.

Comment: So irritated that I couldn't remember my password when answering this online earlier, so I had to be a guest to answer it :(

Answer (score 4):

`NSDate` has no concept of a timezone.  It is created when you use `[NSDate date]` as the number of seconds in GMT from January 1, 2001.  In order to create or print dates in your own timezone, you need to use `NSDateFormatter` methods to adjust this date for your timezone.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11887312/4146745) goes over the concepts behind NSDate quite nicely.

Answer (score 1):

What Adjunct responds is correct, but in your case, the two response are equals because you are comparing two equal "time values". It is independent of Timezone.