# iOS - How to get NSDate with proper timezone based on Simulator location?

Tags: ios, timezone, nsdate, cllocationmanager, cllocation

So i ran across an issue with the simulator in checking time between a server in one timezone vs. my current timezone.

When doing something like this:

```
startDate = [NSDate new]
```

the time associated with startDate is my timezone(Eastern Time Zone). However, my simulated location of the simulator(lat, lon) is a central time zone. For date/time interval comparisons i have failures in the code because while my lat,lon simulator coordinates are in central timezone, startDate is using my system timezone.

Is there a way to get a proper date/time associated with the simulators simulated location?..like converting the lat,lon to a proper NSDate?

Comment: `NSDate objects encapsulate a single point in time, independent of any particular calendrical system or time zone` - the date has no timezone, only the NSDateFormatter for example adds timezone interpretation

Comment: well i really don't need a timezone persay - i just need to right time for the timezone - based on lat, lon. Does the NSDateFormatter provide that somehow?

Comment: you may want to check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485493/get-nsdate-from-nsdate-adjusted-with-timezone?rq=1)