# How to add/minus TimeZone offset in NSDate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimezone

I am getting current GMT time using

```
NSDate * now = [NSDate date];
```

But i want to add/minus timezone offset in date for different city. 
i am getting offset from server.

Example : I am getting +2:30 GMT from server
so i have to add +2:30 GMT in my current GMT time

or if i am getting -6 GMT so how can i minus it from current time.
My question is basically how to add or minus Hours like +2:30

Comment: [`NSDate`s are independent of time zones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485493/get-nsdate-from-nsdate-adjusted-with-timezone/11887312#11887312).

Comment: @albertamg I know but basically i want to add/minus time from current Time using TimeZone offset

Comment: Hope this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27053135/how-to-get-a-users-time-zone

Comment: Get timeinterval, add/minus offset to interval, create new NSDate from new timeinterval.

Comment: I don't think that both question is same and i am not getting how you moderate question

Answer (score 0):

You can set GMT value in date formatter

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSTimeZone *tz = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:9000]; // GMT+2.30
[formatter setTimeZone:tz];
```

Note : 1 hour = 3600 seconds,
So in the above example 2.30 hr = 9000 seconds

Hope this will help you